# Full Calendar Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm super bad at Javascript and am trying to implement the full calendar Jquery plugin. Found here: https://fullcalendar.io/

I thought the default theme looked pretty ugly so I decided that I would make a theme using the Jquery UI ThemeRoller. Found here: https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

According to the documentation, FullCalendar says that it supports theme roller (jquery ui) but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. I tried adding the JS and CSS I got from the theme roller into the page with the calendar and then doing themesystem: 'jquery-ui' in the init for the calendar but still nothing.

Any one know how to specifically make it use Jquery-ui?

Below is my init.js file for the calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.7.0/fullcalendar.min.css' />").appendTo("head");

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    navLinks: true,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, 
    events: '/schedule/data',
    themesystem: 'jquery-ui',
    cache: true,
    eventStartEditable: false,
    eventStop: function(event, delta, revertFunc){
        console.log(event);
        event_data = {
                id: event.id,
                startDate: event.start, 
                endDate: event.end
        }; 

        console.log("Now event data"); 
        console.log(event_data);
        rep = $.ajax({
            url: '/schedule/data/update', 
            data: event_data, 
            type: 'PATCH'
        })
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        window.location.href='/schedule/appointments/'+calEvent.id+'/detail';            
    }
});

});
```

I would love some help with figuring this out. Thank you!

Comment: There is a demo showing you what to include https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.8.2/demos/themes.html

Comment: Turned "themesystem" into "themeSystem" and the appearance changed but the desired theme is still not applied. I was reading up on some examples online, is themename an option or is it deprecated?

Comment: did you actually include the jQueryUI CSS file into your page? In the code above it's not shown. Also I don't know why you load the fullCalendar CSS using an "append" instead of just directly placing that HTML into your page? There seems to be no reason for it.

Comment: Yes, all of the needed files are in there. Jquery is added before all of them as well. I got it to sort of work with the themeSystem change.